# Change password notification email

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, password

By default, when customer changed their password using "Lost your password?" link, an email notification saying "`Password changed for user: ***`" will be sent to Admin's email address. Is there way to change the email address recipient without changing the website's admin email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the email properties are filtered through [wp_password_change_notification_email](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_password_change_notification_email/) before it is sent ([code here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1915)), which you can hook to modify them e.g.

```
function set_password_change_notification_email_to( $email, $user, $blogname ) {
    $email[ 'to' ] = 'someone@else.com';
    return $email;
}
add_filter( 'wp_password_change_notification_email',
            'set_password_change_notification_email_to', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: works perfectly! Thank you!